# Compile error when using initializer list with designator inside a constructor's member initializer list to initialize an anonymous union type

Tags: c++

I have encountered a situation in c++ where initializing an anonymous union member variable fails when I use initializer list with designators inside a member initializer list of a class constructor.

Following snippet might make things clearer:

```cpp
class MyClass {
public:
  MyClass() : my_union({.outer_field = 123}) {}
  union {
    struct {
      int a: 16;
      int b: 16;
    } inner_field;
    int outer_field;
  } my_union;
};
```

Compiler gives the following error:

```
test.cpp: In constructor ‘MyClass::MyClass()’:
test.cpp:6:44: error: no matching function for call to ‘MyClass::<anonymous union>::._6(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
   MyClass() : my_union({.outer_field = 123}) {}
                                            ^
test.cpp:7:9: note: candidate: MyClass::<anonymous union>::<constructor>()
   union {
         ^
test.cpp:7:9: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
test.cpp:7:9: note: candidate: constexpr MyClass::<anonymous union>::<constructor>(const MyClass::<anonymous union>&)
test.cpp:7:9: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘const MyClass::<anonymous union>&’
test.cpp:7:9: note: candidate: constexpr MyClass::<anonymous union>::<constructor>(MyClass::<anonymous union>&&)
test.cpp:7:9: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘MyClass::<anonymous union>&&’
```

However, the following code compiles with no problem;

```cpp
union myunion {
  struct {
    int a: 16;
    int b: 16;
  } inner_field;
  int outer_field;
} my_union;
myunion m = {.outer_field = 123};
```

I can get around the problem by invoking the implicit constructor of union (as the error message suggests) like:

```cpp
class MyClass {
public:
  MyClass() : my_union({123}) {}
  union {
    struct {
      int a: 16;
      int b: 16;
    } inner_field;
    int outer_field;
  } my_union;
};
```

But why does the initializer list with designators don't work within a member initializer list?

The g++ used to compile is version 5.4.0.

```
g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) 5.4.0 20160609
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically the example you give of compiling is not valid c++, but uses a GCC extension to allow C99 designated intializers. The case in question:

```
myunion m = {.outer_field = 123};
```

However, this is not using an initializer list, but uniform initialization.  To get the same result in your code that you had as not compiling, just remove the outer parentheses:

```
class MyClass {
public:
  MyClass() : my_union{.outer_field = 123} {}
  union {
    struct {
      int a: 16;
      int b: 16;
    } inner_field;
    int outer_field;
  } my_union;
};
```

Instead of trying to pass an initializer list to the union's constructor, this performs uniform initialization.  Keep in mind that it still is using a GCC extension, and would generate a warning if you passed -pedantic to the compiler.

EDIT:
Also as a warning, when using uniform-initialization, unions always initialize the first member.  Structs will zero initialize any missing values.  So your first example of the constructor that compiles:

```
MyClass() : my_union({123}) {}
```

This actually sets inner_field to the active field in the union, then a will be 123 and b will be 0.  [Here is an example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Y7iyjL).  See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/struct_initialization) for more details about initializing unions.

Comment: One more question though - what would be the preferred practice in this case - unitializing a union variable within a member initializer list?

Comment: I don't know if I can answer for preferred practice.  Some places expect conforming c++ without extensions, at other places, that is fine.  See my edit that addresses a different part of your question, though.